# Process gets killed when ssh disconnects

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, debian

I'm running the script below on a gcp debian instance. When shutting down my computer, ssh disconnects, and the script stops. Below is my script:

```
wget -P/root -N --no-check-certificate "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reeceyng/v2ray-agent/master/shell/install_en.sh" && mv /root/install_en.sh /root/install.sh && chmod 700 /root/install.sh &&/root/install.sh
```

I have tried Tmux and screen to prevent this based on other posts suggestions. None of them were helpful. All processes stop after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nohup` to detach your process (here, wget) from your shell. For example:

```
 nohup wget -P/root -N --no-check-certificate "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reeceyng/v2ray-agent/master/shell/install_en.sh" && mv /root/install_en.sh /root/install.sh && chmod 700 /root/install.sh &&/root/install.sh &
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Didn't work. It's an interactive script. Here is the detail:
Please select:1
bash: 1: command not found

[2]+  Stopped                 nohup wget -P/root -N --no-check-certificate "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reeceyng/v2ray-agent/master/shell/install_en.sh" && mv /root/install_en.sh /root/install.sh && chmod 700 /root/install.sh && /root/install.sh